# woocommerce remove shipping fee with code

Tags: woocommerce

On the checkout-page on my shop I have a checkbox which can add a fee to the shipping depending on where the customer is located. It goes something like this:

```
if (isset($post_data['add_gift_box']) && $post_data['add_gift_box'] === 'yes') {
        $extracost = 600;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Lives far away', $extracost );
    }
```

I would need a similar button that removes the shipping fee completly.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: You should provide in your question, a more complete code **that is be testable** if you want to get useful working answers… Without that is not possible to guess how your actual code is working and made.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code your active theme function.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_fee' );
function woocommerce_custom_fee() {
global $woocommerce;
    $extracost = 600;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Lives far away', $extracost);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_fee' );
function woocommerce_custom_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
        $payment_method = $woocommerce->session->chosen_payment_method;

        $extracost = 600;
        if ( $payment_method == 'cod' ) { 
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Lives far away', $extracost, false, '' );
        }


}
```